# UPDATE records in one table, several times the message (1 line affected) and then the actual message of the update

Tags: t-sql, update

I have discovered the following oddity:
When I execute a SELECT statement, I get my desired 753 records displayed.
But when I convert this SQL to an UPDATE and I execute an SQL with the following structure, I get "(1 line affected)" several times in the Messages tab (SQL Server Management Studio) Only after several of these messages is the correct message displayed below (753 lines affected).

```
UPDATE table
SET column = value
WHERE   DATEDIFF(MONTH, value1, value2) <> value3
        AND deletedate IS NULL
        AND CONVERT(DATE, date) > '20200101'
```

What's happening in the background?

Comment: Are any triggers defined on the target table?

Comment: I ran it on two client databases. The tables or the complete database structure is absolutely identical. When executing it on customer A, this behavior occurred, but not on customer B. The only difference was that due to the data situation at customer A 753 records were updated and at customer B only 34.